# How to update a property of the last object of a list in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

**I would like to update a property of the last objet stored in a list in mongo**. For **performance reasons**, I can not pop the object from the list, then update the property, and then put the objet back. I can not either change the code design as it does not depend on me. In brief am looking for a way to select the last element of a list.

The closest I came to get it working was to use `arrayFilters` that I found doing research on the subject (mongodb core ticket: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-27089):

```js
db.getCollection("myCollection")
    .updateOne(
    {
        _id: ObjectId('638f5f7fe881c670052a9d08')
    },
    {
       $set: {"theList.$[i].propertyToUpdate": 'NewValueToAssign'}
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [{'i.type': 'MyTypeFilter'}]
    }
)
```

I use a filter to only update the objets in `theList` that have their property `type` evaluated as `MyTypeFilter`.

What I am looking for is something like:

```js
db.getCollection("maCollection")
    .updateOne(
    {
        _id: ObjectId('638f5f7fe881c670052a9d08')
    },
    {
       $set: {"theList.$[i].propertyToUpdate": 'NewValueToAssign'}
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [{'i.index': -1}]
    }
)
```

I also tried using `"theList.$last.propertyToUpdate"` instead of `"theList.$[i].propertyToUpdate"` but the path is not recognized (since `$last` is invalid)

I could not find anything online matching my case.

Thank you for your help, have a great day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to be using Mongo's [pipelined updates](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/), this allows us to use aggregation operators within the update body.

You do however need to consider edge cases that the previous answer does not. (`null` list, `empty` list, and `list.length == 1`)

Overall it looks like so:

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: ObjectId("638f5f7fe881c670052a9d08")
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      list: {
        $concatArrays: [
          {
            $cond: [
              {
                $gt: [
                  {
                    $size: {
                      $ifNull: [
                        "$list",
                        []
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  1
                ]
              },
              {
                $slice: [
                  "$list",
                  0,
                  {
                    $subtract: [
                      {
                        $size: "$list"
                      },
                      1
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              []
            ]
          },
          [
            {
              $mergeObjects: [
                {
                  $ifNull: [
                    {
                      $last: "$list"
                    },
                    {}
                  ]
                },
                {
                  propertyToUpdate: "NewValueToAssign"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5HzxAoWEtRu)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It works indeed, but when the list is empty or null, it creates an object with the only property "propertyToUpdate". It is an issue when deserializing the object: the other properties will be missing. The correct way to handle an empty or null list would be to do nothing: leave the list empty if it was empty or null if it was null

Comment: You can do this in multiple ways, here is a quick [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LeL9syHUiMm) by adding an additional check.

Comment: Indeed, that's perfect, thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use update with pipeline:

```
db.collection.update(
  {_id: ObjectId("638f5f7fe881c670052a9d08")},
  [
    {$set: {
      theList: {
        $concatArrays: [
          {$slice: ["$theList", 0, {$subtract: [{$size: "$theList"}, 1]}]},
          [{$mergeObjects: [{$last: "$theList"}, {propertyToUpdate: "NewValueToAssign"}]}]
        ]
      }
    }}
  ]
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QoiR4PyB-bj)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The only issue here is that it does not work when the list is empty (it works if the list is null though by not doing anything). But when I need to update the last element, I know that the list is not empty, so it works in my case